# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the I18nLanguageInterceptor

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-i18n

After upgrading nest to v8, I'm having problem making nestjs-i18n work.

Here's the Error I'm getting

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the I18nLanguageInterceptor (I18nOptions, I18nResolvers, I18nService, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [3] is available in the I18nModule context.

Potential solutions:
 If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current I18nModule?
 If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within I18nModule?
@Module({
  imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]
 })
 - {"stack":["Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the I18nLanguageInterceptor (I18nOptions, I18nResolvers, I18nService, ?).
 
 Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [3] is available in the I18nModule context.
 
 Potential solutions:
 - If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current I18nModule?
 - If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within I18nModule? 
 @Module({    imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]  })
```

Versions:

```
 "@nestjs/common": "^8.2.0",
 "@nestjs/core": "^8.2.0",
 "nestjs-i18n": "8.2.2",
 "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: are you using a monorepo?

Comment: @MicaelLevi i'm using a monorepo and i have this problem when upgrading to nest 8 can you help me plizz ?

Comment: try to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70355914/5290447

Comment: @MicaelLevi i have core only when executing this command : ls -l node_modules/@nestjs

Answer (score 1):

try installing `jest-mock-extended` package if you're getting error from testcases.

```
import { mockDeep } from 'jest-mock-extended';
import { I18nService } from 'nestjs-i18n';
describe('ZController', () => {
  let controller: ZController;
  const i18nServiceMock = mockDeep<I18nService>();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [ZController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: I18nService,
          useValue: i18nServiceMock,
        },
        {
          provide: HttpService,
          useValue: {
            get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<ZController>(ZController);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**
Your module I18nLanguageInterceptor has to resolve al the dependencies that have in the constructor.
In this case you are having problems with the last (I18nOptions, I18nResolvers, I18nService, ***?***).

Where are you injecting I18nLanguageInterceptor module?, can you show me your app.module or whatever are you building with this I18nLanguageInterceptor module.

Here to help!

Comment: the `I18nLanguageInterceptor` _interceptor_ is not in OP's code, it is loaded from `nestjs-i18n`, and it's fine. The issue here is on how dependencies are being imported. Probably `@nestjs/core` is imported twice, from two differents nodejs modules.

Answer (score 0):

basically, this happens when you have several values of `ModuleRef` class object, making Nest looking up for the wrong one, which makes `x instanceOf ModuleRef` (that's done internally, roughly) returning `false`

This is probably because you have two `@nestjs/core` nodejs modules in your project.

You can find this out by doing

```sh
ls -l node_modules/nestjs-i18n/@nestjs
## will display `core` (which is not expected)

ls -l node_modules/@nestjs
## will display `core` (which is expected)
```

*(assuming a non-monorepo project)*

Comment: how to deal with non monorepo project ? got the same result here

Comment: use [peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) instead of making `@nestjs/*` a hard dependency of some lib that you'll use in your nestjs app