# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmCoreModule

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

**src/contact/contact.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ContactController } from './contact.controller';
import { Contact } from './contact.entity';
import { ContactRepository } from './contact.repo';
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
     TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      Contact,
    ]), 
  ],
  controllers: [ContactController],
  providers: [ContactService, ContactRepository],
})
export class ContactModule {}
```

**src/app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { getMetadataArgsStorage } from 'typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ContactModule } from './contact/contact.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
   TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: 'db',
      entities: getMetadataArgsStorage().tables.map(tbl => tbl.target),
      synchronize: true,
    }), 
    ContactModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**npm new start:dev**

Give this kind of error where I try to find possibly every solution on the internet but what mistake I'm doing I don't know, I got an error like.

**nest -v (8.1.6)**

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmCoreModule (TypeOrmModuleOptions, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmCoreModule?
- If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmCoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]
  })
```

Comment: I believe this is the pretty much the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351643/nest-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-i18nlanguageinterceptor/70355914#70355914

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue as the OP and it does not look like the same issue as Micael Levi pointed out.

Were you able to resolve this? @Kishan Donga

Comment: I made a mistake in database configuration(datasource), and after fixing that, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem because of a bad installation of typeorm.

Works for me:

1- Delete node_module 
2- Run `npm i` 
3- Run `npm install --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm mysql2` again im my project.

Comment: for me this one was enough - npm install --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm

Comment: i also had to delete the dist folder with `sudo rm -rf dist`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error for `TypeOrmCoreModule` when I switched from the globally available `ConfigService` to a custom `EnvConfigService`. In that case, for example, I needed to `import` the module in which the custom `EnvConfigService` resided; as shown in the bold statement below:

```
    const typeOrmModule = TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [EnvConfigModule],
      inject: [EnvConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: EnvConfigService) => {
        return {
          type: 'postgres',
          host: config.postgresHost,
          port: config.postgresPort,
          database: config.postgresDatabaseName,
          username: config.postgresUsername,
          password: config.postgresPassword,
          synchronize: true,
          entities: [User, PasswordRecovery]
        }
      }
    })
```

The `import` statement was not required when I injected `ConfigService` because it's globally accessible.